# How to start Navigation Drawer from JavaScriptInterface

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, navigation-drawer

I have `WebView` to show my web page and I want run `Navigation Drawer` with `Javascript`.

My `logcat` doesn't show any error message but it doesn't run/

My JavaScript:

```
$('body').on("taphold", function ()
{
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
    {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
        {
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
    AndroidFunction.DeleteAll();
}
```

Java:

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void DeleteAll()
    {
        //========== Array ================
        final String[] fragments ={"Delete All"};
        //=================================
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fragments);
        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        navList.setAdapter(adapter);
        navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            @JavascriptInterface
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
                drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                    @Override
                    @JavascriptInterface
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                        switch (pos) {
                            case 0:
                                final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("CopyCollection", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                                mydatabase.execSQL("DELETE * FROM Details;");
                                mydatabase.close();
                                myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:fill_comment()");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody can help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to close the drawer when `DeleteAll` method is called, right? If so, the problem is that you are calling `drawer.closeDrawer(navList)` into the anonymous `OnItemClickListener`. You have to move `closeDrawer` invocation out of the listener object and put it into the `DeleteAll` method scope.

Comment: I changed but nothing happen

Comment: Are you sure your ```javascript``` code is invoced correctly? What about your java code? Set a few breakpoints and logging and check what is happening :)

Comment: I put the `toast` at the start of `DeleteAll()` and it works but other line doesn't work

Comment: Put some ```Log.d(...)``` in places you want to check and check which lines are called and which are not.

Comment: I want create js function that user tap-hold on it navigation drawer be open.did I wrote are correct?

Comment: So... the ```javascript``` you have written does the following: when the user holds on the **body** element, a checkbox i chekced and ```AndroidFunction.DeleteAll();``` is called. The ```javascript``` you have exposed does the following: when called, a new ```ItemClickListener``` is attached to the drawer's ```ListView```. From its point of view this listener attached a new one, that handles the closing of the drawer... I am pretty sure you don't want do it this way. Please explain what you are trying to achieve so I can try to help you :)

Comment: Do you have any update on your problem? If you think I helped you, may I ask you to mark my answer as the correct one? :)